# Emacs Org Mode concept of duration? An easily written and sortable string defining durations

Tags: org-table

Does Emacs Org Mode have a concept of "durations"? Specifically I want to define durations in years, months, weeks, and/or days, and then sort a column of such data.

Possibilities:

- Emacs has such a concept, but how to use?
- There exist string standards for such durations, where? And which is the easiest to type in as a human?
- Make up a string definition for durations. E.g. **1-5-3-2** (1 year, 5 months, 3 weeks, 2 days). And if there is no year you'd just do: **0-5-3-2** so it's sortable, etc.

Comment: Only one question per post, please. Maybe your question is something like *`How can I define durations for Org mode (or Org table?)`*?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you want to achieve, perhaps you could clarify your question. 
Maybe you want to set [Effort Estimates](https://orgmode.org/manual/Effort-Estimates.html)?